# Theming a node teaser to use its content types's custom tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I have a page--contenttype.tpl.php in a custom theme that displays a node exactly how I want it to display on its own node page. How do I make it so that the teaser for the node of that type displays the same as it displays in full view?

I want to add this in either template.php, page.tpl.php or page--contenttype.tpl.php of my custom theme but cannot figure out the best way of doing it

Comment: If you are using Views to construct these lists of teasers, you can use `node--view--NAMEOFTHEVIEW.tpl.php`

Comment: I am not using views. This is a theme written from scratch that uses only the core apis

Comment: `node.tpl.php` can also be extended to `node--TYPE.tpl.php` and within you can use the `$view_mode`, `$teaser` and/or `$page` variables to modify behavior.  See https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656 and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7 for lots more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add template files in your template.php & then add files for them. In your case write something like this in your template.php -

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) { //Replace THEME with your theme name.
  if($vars['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $vars['node']->type . '__teaser';   
  }
}
```

After that, your TPL file for teaser would be in the format of `node--[type]--teaser.tpl.php`. Don't forget to clear your cache after you do this..